Projection and depth map of a parabolic cylinder.
The problem:
I've been working on a project involving 3D graphics and camera projections, and I came across a problem that I need some help with.
I have a parabolic cylinder described by the equation $y'=x'^2$ in 3D space, with $z'$ being free to vary. The parabolic cylinder undergoes a certain rotation (by rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$) and translation (by translation vector $\mathbf{t}$):
$$ \mathbf{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{bmatrix} = 
\mathbf{R} \begin{bmatrix}
x' \\
y' \\
z'
\end{bmatrix} + \mathbf{t}
$$
I have a pinhole camera located at the origin, looking towards the positive $z$-axis. In such a setup, the projection of a point $(x, y, z)^T$ onto the image plane is given by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\
v \\
d
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
fx/z\\
fy/z\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $f$ is the focal length of the camera, $u$ and $v$ are the image plane coordinates, and $d$ is the depth of the point from the standpoint of the camera. See diagram below ($X, Y, Z$ in the diagram are what I denoted $x, y, z$ and $x, y$ are what I denoted $u, v$).

In the context of my project, I have a noisy depth map $d(u,v)$ of a part of the parabolic cylinder from the perspective of the camera, and I need an appropriate model for $d(u,v)$. So my question is: how do I find an expression for $d(u,v)$?
My attempt so far:
The parabolic cylinder is a quadric surface. Thus, the following equation holds for some $3 \times 3$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$, column vector $\mathbf{b}$, and scalar $c$.
$$
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{x} + c = 0
$$
From the pinhole model, we know that
$$
\mathbf{x}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
ud/f\\
vd/f\\
d
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\frac{d}{f} \begin{bmatrix}
u\\
v\\
f
\end{bmatrix} \overset{\Delta}{=} \frac{d}{f} \mathbf{u}
$$
which, combined with the quadric equation, results in
$$
\left( \frac{d}{f} \right)^2 \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u} + \frac{d}{f} \mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{u} + c = 0
\iff d = f \frac{-\mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{u} \pm \sqrt{(\mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{u})^2 - 4c \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}}}{2\mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}}
$$
Is this solution correct? If so, how do I find the correct sign in the numerator? And what geometric situation is represented by the expression inside the square root being negative?
